# where should i put the package folder in spacemacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I see an inetresting package and I want to play around with it. Should I create a layer and then create an extension folder and in that folder I git clone the package ?

The default folder after I run create layer doesnt have the extension folder.

What is correct workflow for my situation?